# Pandas - how often each string in comma separated rows is present within dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with DataFrame containing two columns, one of columns contains comma separated strings, second one contains integers. I want to iterate through column with strings, save each unique string from each row, assign integer value from second column to each string. In other words,

```
A           B
a,b,c,d     0
a,b,c,d     10
a,b,d,e     89
a,b,d,e     111
```

In this example:

```
a = 220, b = 220, c = 10, d = 220, e = 210
```

I am selecting interesting columns from my csv file,

```
revcat = DataFrame(data, columns = ['Tag', 'Revenue'])
```

This gives me ndarray with unique values in 'Tag' and transform it to another DataFrame.

```
uniqtag = rev1.Tag.str.split(",").apply(pd.Series).stack().unique()
tag_stack = pd.DataFrame(uniqtag)
```

I am stuck here. How, based on this, do I iterate through original 'Tag' column, using unique strings I found and sum values from 'Revenue' column to each 'Tag'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do with [`Series.str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html), [`Series.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) and [`Series.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
df['A'].str.get_dummies(sep=',').mul(df['B'], axis=0).sum()

a    210
b    210
c     10
d    210
e    200
```

#### Explanation

```
df.A.str.get_dummies(sep=',')
```

This yields a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  1  1  1  0
1  1  1  1  1  0
2  1  1  0  1  1
3  1  1  0  1  1
```

Then using `.mul` with your value column would yield:

```
     a    b   c    d    e
0    0    0   0    0    0
1   10   10  10   10    0
2   89   89   0   89   89
3  111  111   0  111  111
```

Which finally, applying `.sum` along index axis will give you your final output:

```
a    210
b    210
c     10
d    210
e    200
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I'd use

1. Split on "," and use `expand=True` to get a dataframe back where each letter is in its own column (I'm assuming right now, based on your example, that you always have the same number of splits? Is this true?)
2. "Melt" that dataframe so that instead of having multiple columns created from each row in the original df, you have a long dataframe where each row is a letter and its index in the original df.
3. Convert from the indices to the values in the `B` column
4. Group by the letter and sum across `B`.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ("a,b,c,d", 0),
    ("a,b,c,d", 10),
    ("a,b,d,e", 89),
    ("a,b,d,e", 111),
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["A", "B"])

#   A       B
# 0 a,b,c,d 0
# 1 a,b,c,d 10
# 2 a,b,d,e 89
# 3 a,b,d,e 111

melted = df.A.str.split(",", expand=True).reset_index().melt(id_vars="index", value_name="A")
melted["B"] = df.B.loc[melted["index"]].values
melted.groupby("A").B.sum()

# value
# a    210
# b    210
# c    10
# d    210
# e    200
```

Note - I think you have the sums incorrect in the question; a few of them seem to be off by 10.